# How to handle mediawiki templates in pandoc

Tags: pdf-generation, mediawiki, pandoc, file-conversion, mediawiki-templates

I want to use pandoc to convert pages from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.arch.org) to PDF files. These are `mediawiki` pages. As an example, use the [source for the Creating Packages page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Creating_packages&action=edit) (I saved that source into a file `CreatingPackages.wiki`). Many of these pages use templates, of the form:

```
{{Template name|param1|param2|...}}
```

It's possible to recover the code for these templates (which is HTML code). For example, the template `{{AUR|package}}` has the following definition:

```
<span class="plainlinks archwiki-template-pkg">[https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/{{urlencode:{{{1}}}}}/ {{{1}}}]</span><sup><small>AUR</small></sup>
```

(See the [template source for Template:AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Template:AUR&action=edit), specifically the part in the `includeonly` HTML tags.)

A raw run on one of the Arch Wiki pages will have problems because **pandoc** sees templates and doesn't know what to do with them. For example, here's a conversion command:

```
pandoc -f mediawiki -t pdf CreatingPackages.wiki > test.pdf
```

The resulting PDF is not too bad, but clearly **pandoc** does not know how to handle the templates, which results in missing text and accidental improper formatting.

How can I instruct **pandoc** on what to do with templates?

Comment: This is also a question I asked on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/pandoc/comments/fqslib/for_mediawiki_conversion_how_to_handle_templates/

Comment: currently not, there is an open issue about it: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4404